# Facebook api how to get userid and name?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am using facebook php api for fetching data. Please help me on how to authenticate and fetch userid, name, email, gender.(I HAVE asked for email permission).

Here is my code:

```
require 'facebookcredentials.php';
require 'facebookapi.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

     $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 
    'email,read_stream,publish_stream,create_event,rsvp_event'));
```

Please tell me how to first authenticate the user and then get `$userid, $name, $gender, $email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the example here:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php
it helps a lot...

anyway, you are looking for these: 
 $me = $facebook->api('/me');

see the whole example though.